# Sending large std::vector using MPI_Send and MPI_Recv doesn't complete

Tags: mpi, stdvector

I'm trying to send a std::vector using MPI. This works fine when the the vector is small, but just doesn't work when the vector is large (more than ~15k doubles in the vector). When trying to send a vector with 20k doubles, the program just sits there with the CPU at 100%.

Here is a minimal example

```
#include <vector>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

vector<double> send_and_receive(vector<double> &local_data, int n, int numprocs, int my_rank) {
    MPI_Send(&local_data[0], n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (my_rank == 0) {
        vector<double> global_data(numprocs*n);
        vector<double> temp(n);
        for (int rank = 0; rank < numprocs; rank++) {
            MPI_Recv(&temp[0], n, MPI_DOUBLE, rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                global_data[rank*n + i] = temp[i];
            }
        }
        return global_data;
    }
    return vector<double>();
}

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
    int my_rank, numprocs;
    // MPI initialization
    MPI_Init (&args, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

    int n = 15000;
    vector<double> local_data(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        local_data[i] = n*my_rank + i;
    }

    vector<double> global_data = send_and_receive(local_data, n, numprocs, my_rank);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile using

```
mpic++ main.cpp
```

and run using

```
mpirun -n 2 a.out
```

When I run with `n = 15000` the program completes successfully, but with `n = 17000` or `n = 20000` it never finishes, and the two CPU's sit at 100% until I force close the program.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Send` is a funny call.  If there is enough internal buffers to store the input, it *may* return - the only guarantee it makes is that input buffer is not going to be needed further by MPI.  However, if there isn't enough internal buffer space, the call will block until the opposite `MPI_Recv` call begins to receive data.  See where this is going?  Both processes post `MPI_Send` that block due to insufficient buffer space.  When debugging issues like that, it helps to replace `MPI_Send` with `MPI_Ssend`.

Your possible solutions are:

- Use buffered send, `MPI_Bsend`.
- Use `MPI_Sendrecv`
- Alternate send/recv pair so that each send has a matching recv (e.g. odd proc sends, even recvs, then vice versa).
- Use non-blocking send, `MPI_Isend`

See http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node39.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was just looking into Isend/Irecv. If I just use Isend and Irecv instead in the example, should I add `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)` before receiving?

Comment: No need for Irecv, you only need to have Send return.  No need for barrier either.