# Sending class instances using MPI_Send() or MPI_Bcast in C++

Tags: mpi

How can I transmit instances of my class or a `std::vector` using `MPI_Send()` or `MPI_Bcast()` in C++?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: LMGTFY http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746553/sending-large-stdvector-using-mpi-send-and-mpi-recv-doesnt-complete

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply transmit instances of random classes since being C calls neither `MPI_Send()` nor `MPI_Bcast()` understand the structure of those classes. You can send instances of `std::vector` (since it uses contiguous memory storage) by providing `&vector[0]` to `MPI_Send()` but the receive operation should then be implemented in several steps: `MPI_Probe()` -> get the number of elements in the message -> resize the vector instance -> `MPI_Recv()` into the resized instance. For all other cases, you should use something like [Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/mpi.html) or you should use `MPI_Pack()` and `MPI_Unpack()` to serialise and deserialise your class instances to and from MPI messages.

Answer (score 3):

MPI doesn't operate on objects, it operates on memory locations.  So to send an object from your own class, you will need to know the memory layout from your class.  You can then use this to build an MPI datatype.  There is an entire chapter of the MPI specification (chapter 4) devoted to how to do this.  The basic premise is that you build a datatype based on the standard MPI types, arranged in a specified memory layout.  Once this type is built and committed, you can then use it in MPI operations.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've already found a solution:

http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node83.htm#Node83

in 5th Example

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending it as a byte array like this:

```
MPI_Send(vec.data(), vec.size() * sizeof(VectorElement), MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

And recieve it like this:

```
MPI_Recv(&vec.front(), vec.size() * sizeof(VectorElement), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Where `vec` is an instanse of `std::vector<VectorElement>`
If you think that the receiving vector size could change, you can simply send it before the vector.

I can't guarantee that this method is safe but i believe it should be since both padding and the order of fields of a certain class should be the same on every subprocess.

Comment: That works with contigous plain `C` struct (though not as elegant as using derived datatypes) that do not contain pointers, but generally do not work with C++ classes. better use a higher level library such as `Boost::MPI` that automagically (de)serialize C++ objects.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet In what case won't it work on a C++ object? Assuming there are no pointers envolved. This solution works fine in my C++ project

Comment: That's quite an assumption isn't it? What if your C++ object is a `std::vector<int>` (use different vector sizes to make it fun)?